In Groovy, how can I iterate through a list of maps and print each map's key/value?
I have the following test code where I create a list of Map<String,String> and want to print the key/value of each map in the list.
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy

List<Map<String,String>> list = []
Map<String, String> map1 = ["a":"a"]
list.add(map1)
println list
Map<String, String> map2 = ["b":"b"]
list.add(map2)
println list
list.each { m->
  println "${m.key} ${m.value}"
}

When executing the code, I get
[[a:a]]
[[a:a], [b:b]]
null null
null null

What is the correct way to print each map's key and value in the list?

you have list of maps. so, you need to iterate each map as well:
List<Map<String,String>> list = []
Map<String, String> map1 = ["a":"a"]
list.add(map1)
println list
Map<String, String> map2 = ["b":"b"]
list.add(map2)
println list
list.each { map ->
  map.each{ entry ->
    println "${entry.key} ${entry.value}"
  }
}

